# VW Passat Variant 2016 Diesel engine gets much louder when I turn left/right

Tags: engine, noise, vw, diesel, passat

My car is running well the only issue I have is that the noise the engine makes gets a lot noisier (but its still the same noise) each time I turn the wheels to left or right. The more I turn them the more noisier it becomes. I asked the technicians already but they cant find out why that is.

Comment: Check your power steering pump and its drive mechanism.

Comment: Check your exhaust system.  Possibly the centrifugal force of the turn is causing an exhaust leak making your engine sound louder.  I would start with the exhaust flex pipe.

Answer (score 0):

In a modern car it is somewhat normal.

This is because the idle is precisely controlled to use minimum fuel while maintaining acceptable comfort and reliability.

When you turn the wheel, the idling engine has to double or even triple its output power in order to help you turn the wheels left and right. In a diesel engine, this amounts to doubling or tripling the cycle fuel amount.

Gasoline engines are different in this regard (they are a lot quieter as well).